# MFC grid is absolute layout and gets clipped during window resize

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Using visual studio C++ 2010.

Currently in a window in MFC code I have a grid. I want the grid to "become smaller" if I resize the window (drag the corners manually), but as I resize the window the grid actually is completely static, so e.g. resizing the window to a very small size will cause the edges of the grid to become outside of the window's visibility.

I noticed that the other "objects" within this window (notably, the MFC buttons I have such as "cancel") do scale with the window and don't go out of sight when I resize the window to a smaller size. They follow the window's edges as if they were given smart relative coordinates instead of absolute coordinates that my grid follows.

Currently I am using the grid here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27 although I highly suspect it is not the source of the problem (there is an example code that uses it, and the resize behaves as expected; I cannot compile it but I ran the exe example). I recently switched from MSFlexGrid (because it doesn't support 64 bit) but in the previous version when I used to use MSFlexGrid, it didn't have this problem either.

I thought it might be some sort of window property or object property in the .rc file but I compared the files and found no leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing like a window property that tells window to adjust the size to the size of the parent.

If buttons change size and position, you are probably using some kind of class that takes care of resizing of the child controls.

Follow the same for your grid, or notify grid about the parent size change and adjuxt grid size accordingly.